# laravel relations error Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: laravel-5, relationship

I'm trying to retrieve data from two tables and in order using a hasMany relationship. i.e

```
Public childModel (){
  return $this->hasMany(childModel); 
}
```

In the view when I run the foreach loop:

```
foreach($parentModel as $parentModel)
```

or

```
foreach($parentModel->childModel as $childModel)
```

then

`{{parentModel->childModel}}`

I get json printed on my screen just fine (including the column I want to output.)

When I try

```
`{{parentModel->childModel->column}}`
```

I get *"Trying to get property of non-object"*

Comment: If parentModel->childModel is a jSON string you can't access its properties. You need to decode it first so that you get an object.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I was making a 'where' statments when i initialized the parentModel variable, that 'where' statement rejected the table in the childModel. Only found out after running tests.